# Why is rdfs:XMLLiteral a class and an instance?

Tags: rdf, owl, rdfs

I am new in the field and I am a bit confused about the definition of the RDFS vocabulary.

Specifically, the vocabulary defines that `rdfs:XMLLiteral`, which is a class, is the subclass of `rdfs:Literal` (`rdfs:XMLLiteral` and `rdfs:Literal` are connected using `rdfs:subClassOf`).

This is straightforward and is easily understood. However, the vocabulary also said the class `rdfs:XMLLiteral` is an instance of `rdfs:DataType` (linked by `rdf:type`). So, in this case, why the `rdf:type` is used instead of `rdfs:subClassOf`, given both the `rdfs:XMLLiteral` and the `rdfs:DataType` are classes.

My personal thought is that, because subclass relationship between Class A and B (suppose A ∈ B) implies that every individual that belongs to A also belongs to B.

So suppose we have an "x" which belongs to the `rdfs:XMLLiteral` class, if there was a subclass relationship between `rdfs:XMLLiteral` and `rdfs:DataType`, then "x" is also a `rdfs:DataType`, which is not the fact (because "x" is just an individual literal). Furthermore, because the `rdfs:DataType` and `rdfs:Class` are connected by `rdfs:subClassOf` according to the vocabulary, then "x" is also a class, if the subclass relationship between `rdfs:XMLLiteral` and `rdfs:DataType` existed. Therefore, such a subclass relationship should not exist.

I do not know if my thought here is right, and I hope someone can give some suggestions to help me understand the subclass relationship and instance relationship in the RDFS vocabulary.

[image]

Comment: Note that it’s `rdf:XMLLiteral`, not `rdfs:XMLLiteral`.

Answer (score 3):

If you understand well the set-theoretic relations ∈ and ⊆, then you have a good basis for understanding `rdf:type` and `rdfs:subClassOf`. What you describe about `rdf:XMLLiteral` is pretty accurate. However:

> suppose A ∈ B

This means that A belongs to B, **not** that every individual that belongs to A also belong to B.

`A rdf:type B` could be understood (roughly) as "A ∈ B", while `A rdfs:subClassOf B` could be understood (roughly) as "A ⊆ B".

A set can be an element of another set, as well as included in yet another one, or the same. E.g., {a} ⊆ {a,{a}} and {a} ∈ {a,{a}}.

However, the analogy with set theory is only *roughly* correct because RDF allows classes to be instances of themselves, whereas set theory forbids sets to be elements of themselves (assuming [the axiom of regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity)). The reason why RDF still "works" is due to the way [its semantics](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-mt/) is defined, where `rdf:type` is not really interpreted as the set membership relation, and `rdfs:subClassOf` is not really interpreted as set inclusion.